# How to share a variable among main and subclass in python?

Tags: python, subclass

(Not a profi programmer here, mine is probably a dumb question)

I've a database stored in several ascii files (one file per table) within the same directory.
I'm used to read all files and load each of them in Pandas DataFrame. Eventually I bundle all the dataframes in a single dict variable.
Reading the files from disk takes about 1s.

The DB has several sections describing different groups of objects, each one with their configuration parameters:

```
DB
|
+-TC
|  +-PAR
+-TM
|  +-PAR
+-SEQ
   +-PAR
```

I want to define a module having classes and methods to load, browse and manipulate the data and I'm wondering which is the best approach with the constrain **to read the db from disc only once**.

**Option 1 [preferred]:** have a class/subclass structure mimic the DB organisation.

The desired usage would be something like:

```
db = DB()
dbdata= db.load(dir)
print( db.version())
tcName = DB.TC('tcName')
print(tcName.description)
tcName.PAR('param1').setvalue(value1)
```

module:

```
class DB:
   def __init__(self):

   def load(self, dbDir):
      self.db = read_all_db_files_from_dbDir
      return self.db

   def version(self):

   class TC:
      def __init__(self, tcName):
         self.tcName = tcName
      def description(self)
      def parametes(self)

      class PAR:
         def __init__(self, tcParName):    
            self.parName = tcParName     
         def description(self)
         def setvalue(self, value)
[...]
   class SEQ:
      [...definitions similar to TC...]

      class PAR
         def __init__(self, seqParName):    
            self.parName = seqParName     
         def description(self)
         def setvalue(self, value)
```

**Option 2**: flat class structure.

```
class DB:
   def load(self, dbDir):
      self.db = read_all_db_files_from_dbDir
      return self.db

   def version(self):

class TC:
   def __init__(self, tcName, dbData):
      self.tcName = tcName
      self.dbData = dbData

   def description(self)
   def parametes(self)

class TCPAR:
   def __init__(self, tcParName, dbData):
      self.tcParName = tcParName
      self.dbData = dbData

   def description(self)
   def setvalue(self, value)

[... and so on also for the SEQ and SEQPAR classes]
```

In this case I suppose I need to pass the db variable when calling each method:

```
db = DB()
dbData = db.load(dir) 
tcName = TC('tcName',dbData)
print(tcName.description)
param1 = TCPAR('param1',dbData)
param1.setvalue(value1)
```

Option 1 question: *how can I pass the variable self.db to the subclasses without reloading the db every time I use a subclass/method?*

Option 2 question: *any other way to share the variable dbData among the classes?*

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? It may make more sense to have one `DB` object that reads through the entire file and creates your Pandas df and dictionary all in an internal method, instead of setting up things like triple-nested classes which are almost certainly more work than you need.

Answer (score 0):

You coud make the variables global with the `global` tag:

```
global var_global
var_global = 'test'
```

It would look something like this in a class with subclasses:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, var):
        global var_global
        var_global = var

    class sub:
        def __init__(self):
            print('Output:', var_global)


tst = test('test')
tst.sub()
```

Output:

```
Output: test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think there are much better solutions than this one but i think it fits your idea. :)